# how to solve "No pyenv.cfg file" error when commit to git on desktop app

Tags: git, github, virtualenv

My local branch seems to be working fine for me but whenever I want to make a commit through github desktop app, it is giving me this error. I can see the pyenv.cfg file in the virtual environment that I use but I don't understand why Git is complaining about it since I am not committing anything like virtual environments anyway.
[The error message I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0m2m.png)

Comment: Are there any valid git hooks under `.git/hooks`? You can also check if `git config core.hookspath` returns a path that contains hooks.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by removing a virtual environment folder within the repo. Thanks